# How to deploy on apache http server once you have your angular2 application bundled with gulp

Tags: javascript, apache, angular, gulp

I've been wasting a lot of time trying to learn how to deploy angular 2. I tried looking around how to do it on tomcat, because that's what I was ordered to do, but turns out tomcat isn't really used for this, is more java and jsp oriented, so I've read is better to use Apache HTTP server instead.

I just installed Apache server, and I just installed npm with gulp ( https://github.com/swirlycheetah/generator-angular2 ), and everything works fine: I can run my app on localhost:3030 with gulp **but I now want to test it with Apache**,

I've tried several things (since I haven't seen one single place explaining this, maybe it's a very basic thing to do?):

- Configure apache .conf file to change the htdocs to a folder I've created. I've tested this works, I see the result on screen when I access localhost.
- Compiled everything, got a folder called build with all my files changed to .js extention, so I figured, that must be it. I copied all the files in there, the lib folder created, and index.html and css files. Doesn't work.
- Tried several combinations of picking some files that I figured would be necessary and not others. Doesn't work.
- Copied the whole project that I've tested with gulp, with eclipse etc that works, **including .ts and .d.ts files, which I've read shouldn't be there and are not necessary**, and it works.

So I would like to know how is this really done, because I feel like I'm making no improvements. After reading post after post and blog after blog about I simply needed to transpile .ts files to .js, and simply put that javascript files on "some" folder the server uses, it would work. Not only it doesn't but when I use the original .ts files it does.

What might be going on and more important, how is this deployment (I guess it's called something else since I can't find much anything) properly done?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your .js file paths in your index.html page are correct. When you generate .js files in a folder(like build), your index.html may keep source paths for those .js files are like src="inline.js". So when you access index.html in build folder - localhost/build, it looks for those .js files in localhost only not localhost/build. Try to update source path of those .js files to /build/.
src="/build/inline.js".

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using proxy option in Browser Sync..
[proxy option link](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy)

I didn't try it but may be it will help you.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)